# Relation to autoincrement column, force value > 0?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, table-relationships

We usually use autoincrement columns to add identifiers to table rows. Those values are generated as positive integers by mysql.

When I want to model a relation between two tables I use columns of type `unsigned int` to store the foreign keys. `unsigned int`s can store int values including `0`. As `0` is not a valid value for relations I would like to disallow those values.

**Question:** Is there any way to define a column that can only hold positive integers > 0?

Comment: Note that "relation" in relational databases refer to tables, not foreign key constraints.  Relations between entities are represented by associating the primary keys of the entities in a table.  Columns of the same domain in different tables are artifacts of decomposing a relation graph into discrete relations.  They don't represent relationships among entities.  Foreign key constraints are integrity constraints, not relationships.

Comment: What do you want to happen if someone tries to `INSERT` a '0'?